# Symfony: How to automated testing all urls in routing.yml?

Tags: symfony1, routes, url-routing

I have deployed a website based on SF 1.3.8. I have just found out that some of the urls are not working. I would like to create a test that will automatically test all of the routes I have defined in apps/frontend/confi/routing.yml

Does anyone know how I may go about doing this - so I may automate this test?

Comment: You can't. The test will need to have valid parameters to pass to the route.... Furthermore, how will you test a route if some of them are user based? i.e. forward404 if user doesn't have permission etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Jamie points out, you can't really automate this. What you can do though is use the `app:routes` task to return a list of all routes and use that as a checklist to build tests. You can use [Symfony's functional testing](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/15-Unit-and-Functional-Testing) tool to create tests that check each route, including performing a login to test secure routes.

[swFunctionalTestGenerationPlugin](https://github.com/rande/swFunctionalTestGenerationPlugin) is a very useful tool for generating the functional tests themselves. Make one for each route, then tick it off your list. Once you've got a full suite, you can run the tests from the command line as part of your source control process, or as a scheduled task.